# laravel eloquent: get model with all associated relations (recursively)

Tags: recursion, laravel, model, eloquent

Lets say I have a model "A" and it has a relation to "B". B has a relation to C.

Thats so far pretty easy due to Eloquent =)

**But What if "C" can have a relation to another brand new "B"** which can then have relations to other "C"s.

This would mean we have a recursion here and I can not simply query a complete "A" with **all corresponding relations**

Is there a way to resolve the recursion here:

```
$a = A::with(array(
  'b',
  'b.c',
  'b.c.b',
  'b.c.b.c',
  ..recursion..
));
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Not possible unless you specify relations or use dynamic call (not eager loaded).

Comment: Hi! Yes, I specified relations. The relations are not the problem at all but the recursively fetch of them. I want them to be resolved automatically and looking here for a solution.

Comment: I meant that, if you don't use `with('explicit relations here')` or use without `with` and load them on run time using dynamic call.

Comment: This would work but thats not what I am looking for :)

Comment: So what you are saying is a C can have many foreign keys each linking back to the same table of B?

Comment: "B1" has a relation to "C1", "C1" has a relation to "B2", "B2" could have a ralation to "C2" and so on.